# Javascript refactoring. Dealing with repeat code

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I have the following code:

```
  switch(equipmentAttachment.AttachmentPosition)
  {
    case 'AttachFront':
    {
      if(equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryDesc!='')
      {
        attachments.frontAttachment=equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryDesc;
      }
      else
      {
        attachments.frontAttachment=equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryName;
      }
      break;
    }
    case 'AttachRear':
    {
      if(equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryDesc!='')
      {
        attachments.backAttachment=equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryDesc;
      }
      else
      {
        attachments.backAttachment=equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryName;
      }  
      break;        
    }
    case 'Tertiary':
    {
      if(equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryDesc!='')
      {
        attachments.thirdAttachment=equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryDesc;
      }
      else
      {
        attachments.thirdAttachment=equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryName;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  return attachments;
```

Notice that most of the code is kind of repetitive accept for the setting of different properties in the object `attachments`.  Is there anyway to get rid of the repetitive code?  Or is it just what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var posMap = {
  "AttachFront": "frontAttachment", 
  "AttachRear": "backAttachment", 
  "Tertiary": "thirdAttachment"
};
if(posMap[equipmentAttach.AttachmentPosition])
{
  var target = posMap[equipmentAttach.AttachmentPosition];
  attachments[target] = (equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryDesc || equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryName);
}
return attachments;
```

Update: slightly more succinct:

```
var target = {
  "AttachFront": "frontAttachment", 
  "AttachRear": "backAttachment", 
  "Tertiary": "thirdAttachment"
}[equipmentAttach.AttachmentPosition];
if(target)
{
  attachments[target] = (equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryDesc || equipmentAttachment.ProductCategoryName);
}
return attachments;
```